# How to prepend a PREFIX to paths only once (in an idempotent way) in `sed` (e.g., no PREFIXPREFIX)?

Tags: regex, sed, path, idempotent

I have a file with a complex multi-line command and some unrelated text. I need to prepend certain paths (for example, `/foo`) with a prefix `/bar`. The script may ran more than once, but must not prepend multiple `/bar` prefixes to the same path. For example, run the script once to get `/bar/foo`, run it again, and *still* get `/bar/foo`, not `/bar/bar/foo`. **I must use `sed` for consistency with the existing code base.**

I came up with the desired result (below), but my method seems cumbersome. Is there a better (shorter, less repetitive) way?

```
$ echo '/foo' > infile
$ cat infile 
"/foo" /foo

# Replace once, change expected:
$ sed -i '\#bar/foo#!s#\(/foo\)#/bar\1#g' infile
$ cat infile 
"/bar/foo" /bar/foo

# Replace twice - no change expected:
$ sed -i '\#bar/foo#!s#\(/foo\)#/bar\1#g' infile
$ cat infile 
"/bar/foo" /bar/foo
```

**EDIT: Do not use my "solution": it is wrong in an important edge case, see the comments below**

Comment: What should be output for input line as `"/bar/foo" /foo` ?

Comment: @anubhava It should be `"/bar/foo" /bar/foo`. No matter how many times the script is executed. Never add more than a single `/bar` before any `/foo`. If it is already there, do not add.

Comment: ok in that case the suggested sed solution won't work  for this line

Comment: Yep. I agree. One more reason to reject my "solution", this time for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` solution with an optional group to replace `/foo` with `/bar/foo` but skip matching when `/bar` is already there:

```sh
sed -E 's~(/bar)?(/foo)~/bar\2~g' file
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/62EWIJ/1)

**Details:**

- `(/bar)?`: Match *optional* `/bar` in capture group #1
- `(/foo)`: Match `/foo` in capture group #2
- `/bar\2`: Replacement to always put `/bar` followed by value we captured in capture group #2

Comment: This works exactly as intended. To modify the file in place, add `-i` modifier to `sed`. I also like tilde (`~`) as the regex delimiter: makes it slightly more readable.